# Como apertar o botão de um site em python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Estou fazendo um webscrapping do site do cifra club e pegando as músicas mais acessadas de um gênero.

O código funciona normal mas o jeito que a página é feita só aparecem as 100 primeiras músicas, pra mostrar o resto eu tenho que fisicamente clicar no botão "Mostrar Mais" do site. Apertar o botão não altera nada na url que eu possa usar no programa pra acessar mais páginas.

```
<button id="js-top_more" class="btn btn-full g-sb">mostrar mais</button>
```

E depois disso não tem mais nada relacionado ao botão.

Existe alguma maneira de contornar esse problema?

Comment: Está usando selenium?

Comment: Eu só estou usando o beautifulsoup

Comment: Com `beautifulsoup` não faz muito sentido pensar em clicar em botões. Você tem duas alternativas: usar selenium (controlar um navegador de verdade com código) ou analisar e replicar as requisições do site, usando as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador.

Comment: Sugestão: Tente contato com o dono do site para saber se não existe uma API pública que você possa usar. Normalmente o web-scrapping é algo não autorizado nos termos de uso da maioria dos sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma biblioteca bastante intuitiva para controlar um navegador pelo Python (desde acessar urls a obter elementos específicos da página e clicar em botões) é o **Selenium**.

Para instalá-lo para o Python 2.*:

```
pip install selenium
```

E para o Python 3.*:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Após a instalação para o Python 3.*, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.cifraclub.com.br/mais-acessadas/")

btn_more = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'js-top_more')
btn_more.click()
```

Clicar no botão em questão vai exibir 20 novas músicas a cada clique, e mantém o mesmo ID (o que pode ser bastante prático pra você), então analise quantas músicas você pretende carregar.

Outra dica que posso te dar é usar o **WebDriverWait**, que faz o *driver* esperar o aparecimento de um elemento com base em um tempo de delay e **expected_conditions**, que oferecerá condições para o WebdriverWait, o que pode ser fundamental entre um clique e outro no botão.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.cifraclub.com.br/mais-acessadas/")

while(sua_condicao):
    btn_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'js-top_more')))
    btn_more.click()
```